# How to avoid unique key appear twice in PySpark left join

Tags: python, join, pyspark

`df_1` column -> `|id|pym_cat|sub_status|year|month|day|`

`df_2` column -> `|id|loc_provinsi|loc_kabupaten|loc_kecamatan|`

Here's my code

`df_join = df_1.join(df_2, df_1.id == df_2.id, "left")`

the error message

`AnalysisException: "Reference 'id is ambiguous, could be: b.id, id.;"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alias one of the df. You then can drop columns conditionally by prefixing the column with alias

```
df.join(df1.alias('df1'),how='left',on=df.id==df1.id).drop(df1.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [withColumnRenamed](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumnRenamed.html) to rename overlapping column to a different name, and drop it at the end:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_join = df_1.alias("df_1") \
              .join(df_2.withColumnRenamed("id", "id2").alias("df_2"), 
                    F.col("df_1.id") == F.col("df_2.id2"), 
                    "left") \
              .drop(F.col("df_2.id2"))
```

Or keep the duplicate column names; but access them by [alias](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.alias.html) to dataframe:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_join = df_1.alias("df_1") \
              .join(df_2.alias("df_2"), 
                    F.col("df_1.id") == F.col("df_2.id"), 
                    "left") \
              .drop(F.col("df_2.id"))
```

Comment: AnalysisException: "Reference 'df_1.id' is ambiguous, could be: df_1.id, df_1.id.;"

Comment: Looks like you have a typo in alias. Second alias should be "df2". Please copy paste the exact code and run without modification to prevent typo errors.